# Shopping Cart Price rule - tiered

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Im looking to set up a shopping cart price rule.

The sale is:

10% off the first item

20% off 2nd item

30% off 3rd item and each additional item

The price rule would be applied to specific categories and I do not want coupon code used.  I need the discount to be applied at checkout.

Please help as I dont know how to set this up.

Thank you!
Krystle

Answer (score 2):

You will have create three rules for that and have to include the categories in which you want to apply discount in each of them. Please review the screenshot below and you will get it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please follow the steps as shown in screenshot and it will work for you.

**[EDIT]**

Please make stop further rules processing to YES

Comment: Hi Dexter! Thank you for answering my question. I have set up the rule as the screenshots show but when I add items to my cart, it is only taking 1 of the rules.  I need it so that if a customer wants to purchase 2 items they will get 10% off the 1st item AND 20% off the 2nd item and if they purchase 3 items it is 10% off the 1st, 20% off the 2nd and 30% off the 3rd.  Right now if there are 3 items its only giving 30% entire order. Do you know how to fix this?  Thank you, Krystle

Comment: that can't be done using default magento promotional rules. You will have to extension the functionality on your own or search for the extension having such functionality

Comment: do you know if I could set it up with a coupon code instead?

Comment: or can you recommend an extension?  I could only find 1 - http://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html

Comment: I dont know much about it.. i haven't use such an extension till now..